# I am trying to read the pixels from a bitmap file in C and ignore the padding. But my algorithm causes an error

Tags: c

the function is as follows:

```
<pre><code>
void readPixelsBMP(FILE* file, struct Pixel** pArr, int width, int height) {
  int padding = (width%4);
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)  {
           unsigned char b,g,r;
            fread(&b, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
            fread(&g, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
            fread(&r, sizeof(unsigned char), 1, file);
            pArr[i][j].b = b;
            pArr[i][j].g = g;
            pArr[i][j].r = r;
            if (j == height - 1) {
              //this line is the problem \/
                fseek(file, sizeof(char) * padding, SEEK_CUR);
            }
        }
    }  
}

</code></pre>
```

Where did I go wrong here?

I had expected the fseek line to skip over the padding. I do not know why it caused an error instead. Sadly my compiler does not give me a reason for the error, it only says exited code -1. I looked at some similar posts but those use algorithms that I do not understand to get around the padding.

Comment: Just from a cursory glance, it looks like you might not be accounting for the file header and specifically the pixelArray offset. Also it looks like V5 headers tell you what the bitmask is for RGBA. This looks like you are just assuming it starts at the beginning of the file and that it is in BGR format with no alpha channel?

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/75/BMPfileFormat.svg

Comment: I am reading the header and dib header, just in a different function. Those functions work fine. My problem is in reading the pixels. My assignment is working with pictures that are pretty standardized in being BGR format with no alpha channel. The size of the header and dib header are also the same

Comment: You could try swapping the current _column major_ approach to _row major_... Or are you attempting to transpose the image while loading it?

Comment: you could check `errno` to hopefully glean more info on what's happening, looks like it will be [`EINVAL` or `ESPIPE`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fseek.3.html)

Comment: Calculate the padding correctly. This might do: `int padding = (4 - (width%4) ) % 4;`

Comment: Just simply trying to load the image into the structs I created. I have an array of pixel structs (a pixel struct is only 3 chars B, G and R)

Comment: Thank you Fe203, I will fix my padding calculation. After troubleshooting more I found any value of the second argument of fseek causes the error.

Comment: Or, is it `(width * 3 ) % 4` instead of simply `(width%4)`??? Having a not-so-great day focussing...

Comment: @AshtonS Rather than read 1/3 of a pixel with each `fread()`, consider 1 `fread()` of a rows of pixels including the padding.

Answer (score 1):

The padding is wrong, 0 okay, 1 = 3, 2 okay, 3 = 1. Mind that `width % 4` will be the last bytes written.

Also the loops are wrongly nested,
and the padding should be applied *after* the inner loop.

```
int padding = (4 - ((3*width) % 4)) % 4;

for (int row = 0; row < height; ++row) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width; ++col) {
        ...
    }
    ... skip padding
    if (padding != 0) {
        fseek(file, padding, SEEK_CUR);08
    }
}
```

Padding can be expressed nicer.

---

The code is slow, treating every single byte. Also be aware that .bmp is a terrible Windows format with several variations and start offsets. And no compression.

Comment: Thanks! I will correct this now. I found that the error I am getting is from the fseek statement though. It seems any value I give it in in it's second argument causes the error "exit status -1"

Comment: I have written down the padding. Doing padding on the width for reading by row must be done as above, `height` times, and not as you do `width` times. If the width is larger than the height one reads outside the file boundary.

Comment: Anybody know why I am getting an error still from fseek? Do I have to use a special include statement for fseek or something? Basically every time I use it in my code I get the error.

Comment: I would write to stdout the file offsets (`ftell`), and other info. That could surprise.

Comment: When using fread you can also use fseek (studio.h). fread and fseek also return return codes.

Comment: So plugging in the current file position using ftell into fseek? I am not sure how that works.

Comment: No but you may output loop starts with the file position. You should reach the end of the file, but I doubt it.

Comment: You may be able to read half the image and check it. Bye

Comment: @Fe2O3 stupid from me, thanks. Corrected

Comment: @Fe2O3 Does your nickname imply a fondness of the language Rust?